# Vuejs template restriction in main script

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

When creating a Vue app I noticed that Vue does not allow templates like this:

```
new Vue({
  template: `
    <div> 1 </div>
    <div> 2 </div>
    <div> 3 </div>
  `,
```

Instead it requires everything to be wrapped in one element like this:

```
new Vue({
  template: `
    <div>
      <div> 1 </div>
      <div> 2 </div>
      <div> 3 </div>
    </div>
  `,
```

This restriction does not apply to child components.

Is there a way around it ? I'd like to not use unnecessary DIVs in the markup just to please Vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in Vue you must have exactly one root element in template:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#A-Single-Root-Element

If you need workaround you could use this plugin:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-fragments